# Music plays when volume turn off

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-audio, system-sounds

I have next issue: 
I use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` to play short sound in my app. But something happens wrong: when I turn off volume on the device - sound still playing. 
I found this issue on devices with iOS 6.0 and greater. On iOS 5 device all right. 
Can anybody point me what I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: When you “turn off volume on the device”, what icon appears on the screen? Is it the bell or the speaker?

Comment: It is a speaker. And when I increase/decrease volume on device - sound in my app plays with the same volume.